Axler Theorem 5.18: $\text{null}(T)$ and $\text{range}(T)$ are invariant under $T$.
I am trying to understood Axler's proof of Theorem 5.18. It states that: if $T$ is a linear operator from $V$ to $V$ and $p$ is a polynomial with coefficients in the field $F$, then $\text{null} p(T)$ and $\text{range} p(T)$ are invariant under $T$.
I'll focus on $\text{null} p(T)$ as the proofs are similar and both hinge on a step that I'm not following. I need to show that if $u \in \text{null} p(T)$, then $T(u) \in \text{null} p(T)$. So I have to show that $(p(T))(Tu) = 0$ given that $p(T) u = 0$. Axler's one-line proof of this is:
$$
(p(T))(Tu) = T(p(T) u) = T(0) = 0. 
$$
The first equality is what is tripping me up. He seems to interchange $p(T)$ and $T$, and I don't understand why he can do that. He proves in the previous theorem that two polynomials applied to an operator commute, but $T$ is acting on $u$, rather than another operator. I considered trying to expand this. So let $p(z) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i z^i$. Then $p(T) = \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i T^i$, so
\begin{align*} 
(p(T))(Tu) &= \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i T^i\right)(Tu) \\
&= \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i T^{i+1} (u) \\
&= \sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i T(T^i (u)) \\
&= T\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i T^i (u) \right) \\
&= T(p(T) u).
\end{align*}
Is this the idea? I can use associativity of $T^{i+1}$ to write this act the operator $T$ acting on $T^i (u)$ and then linearity of $T$, which I think gives me the first equality in Axler's proof.

Your argument is correct. It may be useful to notice that if $V$ is a $k$-vector space and $k[x]$ denotes the ring of polynomials in one variable $x$ with coefficients in $k$, then a homomorphism of rings $\theta \colon k[x] \to \text{End}(V)$ which is $k$-linear (and takes multiplication in $k[x]$ to composition in $\text{End}(V)$) is determined by the image $\theta(x)$ of $x$ in $\text{End}(V) = \text{Hom}(V,V)$, and any element $T \in \text{End}(V)$ gives rise to a ring homomorphism $\theta\colon k[x]\to \text{End}(V)$ with $\theta(x)=T$. This follows from the fact that if $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ and $\theta$ is a $k$-linear ring homomorphism, then $\theta(f) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \theta(x)^i$ -- that is, $\theta(f)$ is obtained simply by "substituting" $T$ for $x$.
Now the image of $\theta$ is commutative, since $k[x]$ is commutative, indeed this is, as already noted in the OP, a consequence of the fact that $T^n = T^m \circ T^{n-m} = T^{n-m}\circ T^m$ is well-defined in an associative algebra. Thus just as $f_1(x)f_2(x) = f_2(x)f_1(x)$ for any two polynomials $f_1,f_2$
in $k[x]$, we have $f_1(T)f_2(T) = f_2(T)f_1(T)$ in $\text{End}(V)$.
The classification of linear endomorphisms $T$ (e.g. as given by Jordan normal form when $k=\mathbb C$) is obtained by studying $T$ from the perspective of the homomorphism $\theta$: for example, the minimal polynomial $m_T$ of $T$ is just the monic polynomials which generates $\ker(\theta)$, so that by the first isomorphism theorem, the image of $\theta$, which is just the $k$-algebra generated by $T$, is isomorphic to $k[x]/\langle m_T\rangle$.

You're working too hard. We have
$$\begin{align*}
(p(T))(Tu)&=(p(T)T)u&&\text{by definition of composition}\\
&=(Tp(T))u&&\text{by 5.17(b) with }q(z)=z\\
&=T(p(T)u)&&\text{by definition of composition}\\
&=T(0)&&\text{since }u\in\mathop{\mathrm{null}}p(T)\\
&=0&&\text{since }T\text{ is linear}
\end{align*}$$
You're unnecessarily reproving a special case of 5.17 when $q(z)=z$.
Note the composition fact has nothing to do with polynomials or linear maps. If $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ are arbitrary functions, then by definition
$$(g\circ f)(x)=g(f(x))$$
for all $x\in X$.
